# CentOS7: copy file and preserve SELinux context

Tags: linux, phpmyadmin, cp, selinux

In order to configure my CentOS system, I'd like to overwrite an arbitrary file preserving almost every attribute but timestamp and content.

As an example, I'll use `/etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php`

Note: file being copied is in other filesystem

```
[root@localhost phpMyAdmin]# ls -laZ /etc/phpMyAdmin/
drwxr-x---. root apache system_u:object_r:etc_t:s0       .
drwxr-xr-x. root root   system_u:object_r:etc_t:s0       ..
-rw-r-----. root apache system_u:object_r:etc_t:s0       config.inc.php
[root@localhost phpMyAdmin]# /bin/cp -frv --backup=numbered --preserve=mode,ownership,context,xattr config.inc.php /etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php 
«config.inc.php» -> «/etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php» (respaldo: «/etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php.~1~»)
[root@localhost phpMyAdmin]# ls -laZ /etc/phpMyAdmin/
drwxr-x---. root apache system_u:object_r:etc_t:s0       .
drwxr-xr-x. root root   system_u:object_r:etc_t:s0       ..
-rw-r-----. root apache system_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0 config.inc.php
-rw-r-----. root apache system_u:object_r:etc_t:s0       config.inc.php.~1~
[root@localhost phpMyAdmin]# systemctl restart httpd
```

When I tried `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`, fist time I get a SELinux warning, and Apache can't access the file.

```
[root@localhost phpMyAdmin]# chcon --reference /etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php.~1~ /etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php
[root@localhost phpMyAdmin]# ls -laZ /etc/phpMyAdmin/
drwxr-x---. root apache system_u:object_r:etc_t:s0       .
drwxr-xr-x. root root   system_u:object_r:etc_t:s0       ..
-rw-r-----. root apache system_u:object_r:etc_t:s0       config.inc.php
-rw-r-----. root apache system_u:object_r:etc_t:s0       config.inc.php.~1~
[root@localhost phpMyAdmin]# systemctl restart httpd
```

Now apache can read the file.

How can I make cp preserve the SELinux context of the original file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the cp documentation, the switch "--preserve=context" allows to copy the Selinux context as well during the process.

Please have a look to this excellent documentation from redhat, it explains the topic wonderfully in an human language:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Working_with_SELinux-Maintaining_SELinux_Labels_.html

Comment: I've tried many cp options (those indicated in the link), --preserve=context and --no-preserve=context, but the result is always the same, apache can't use the file and the **unlabeled_t** attribute is set. Only using chcon after the copy apache can use the file. Perhaps a bug in cp?

Comment: Hi Carlos, is the destination file on a different file system? Which file system type? Where do you mount the volume?

Comment: Source filesystem is ext4, mounted on /mnt/shared. Destination (root) filesystem is ext3.

Comment: Source filesystem is ext4, mounted at /mnt/shared, Root (destination) filesystem is ext3.

Comment: I've developed a script to set the context from destination to source, before copying the file.